# Ionic cordova-plugin-android-permissions not showing while installation

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have followed the official documentation from [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions/).
I have updated my app.component.ts like below:

```
constructor(private androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions) {

platform.ready().then(() => {
this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA, this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.GET_ACCOUNTS]);

.....
});

}
```

This is working as expected.

Now the problem is, the app is asking permission after installation (Not while installing). First time when the app is loaded after accepting permission it is not able to access camera.
Now if I close the app and open again, its able to access the camera.

So the summery is: **The app is not able to access the camera when first time launched. From second time onward its working perfectly.**

As per my understanding, My home page is loading before the app.component.ts executes fully. I have to hold the home page loading till user accepts the permission. Or this can be solved if the app asks permission while installation.
But I am unable to implement any of the above solution. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain permissions in Android require a runtime check, such as the camera permission. Before Android 6 it was only necessary to add permissions to the manifest, however since Android 6 you must verify a permission at runtime.

A user can at any point revoke a permission (see android app settings). You can at no point rely on a permission. Before your app uses the camera a `checkPermission` call is obligatory!

Comment: What about Storage (Read/Write) permission ?

Comment: Since API Level 19 the read/write permission  for external storage is not required anymore, see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score -1):

androidPermissions.requestPermissions should return a promise, try putting your code after the promise resolves as follows:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA, this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.GET_ACCOUNTS]).then(
      result => {
          console.log('User allowed access to camera');
          // put your code here
          alert("Camera Enabled!");
      },
      err => { console.error('User denied access to camera!'); }
    );
});
```

Comment: I think you have not understood the question. How can I put my home.html code inside a promise in app.component.ts?

Comment: one solution might be set your home.html as loading page, and once your promise resolves/rejects navigate to the actual home, this way you'll always have checked for permissions before displaying the actual home page.